# Solidity - Stack Too Deep

Tags: solidity

I'm new to coding and I can't find a way to solve this Stack too deep error in Solidity

```
function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tMarketing) = _getTValues(tAmount);
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate());
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing);
}
```

I am getting the error on line 3 after adding tMarketing.

I have tried to solve my problem using the logic displayed here: https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep

I just don't know how to properly apply it...

I need help. Thanks y'all

Here's the dependencies of the _getValues() function - the _getTValues() and _getRValues() (and their dependencies)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract STACKTOODEEP {

```
uint256 public _taxFee = 3; // 3% Redistributed to all holders
uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;

uint256 public _liquidityFee = 3; // 3% Sent to PancakSwap Liquidity Pool
uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

uint256 public _charityFee = 2; // 2% Sent to Charity Wallet
uint256 private _previousCharityFee = _charityFee;

uint256 public _marketingFee = 2; // 2% Sent to Marketing Wallet
uint256 private _previousMarketingFee = _marketingFee;

function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
    return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
        10**2
    );
}

function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
    return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(
        10**2
    );
}

function calculateCharityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
    return _amount.mul(_charityFee).div(
        10**2
    );
}

function calculateMarketingFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
    return _amount.mul(_marketingFee).div(
        10**2
    );
}

function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tMarketing) = _getTValues(tAmount);
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate());
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing);
}

function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tCharity = calculateCharityFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tMarketing = calculateMarketingFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
    return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing);
}

function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tMarketing, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rMarketing = tMarketing.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity).sub(rCharity).sub(rMarketing);
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and share dependencies of the `_getValues()` function - the `_getTValues()` and `_getRValues()` (and their dependencies) so it's possible to reproduce (and troubleshoot) your issue.

Comment: Edited to add dependencies of the _getValues() function - the _getTValues() and _getRValues() (and their dependencies) @PetrHejda

Comment: It seems that this line `uint256 tMarketing = calculateMarketingFee(tAmount);` called from the `_getTValues` function fails. Can you include it as a dependency as well?

Comment: Hi, sorry as I said I am new to coding so I'm not too good at sharing my code. I have edited my question. I hope this time you have all you need. Thanks a lot for helping me I appreciate it @PetrHejda

Comment: Please paste your entire code next time...

Answer (score 0):

```
(uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate());
```

This line generates an error (see the message below), because the `_getRate()` function is not defined in your code.

> DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. --> Test.sol:45:125: | 45 | (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate()); | ^^^^^^^^

From the context, it seems like you're copying parts of the code from an existing source. Make sure you include the `_getRate()` function as well.

*For testing purposes, I created a dummy function like this:*

```
function _getRate() private view returns (uint256) {
    return 1;
}
```

---

Then you're going to run into issues with undefined functions of the SafeMath library, specifically `mul()` (multiplication), `div()` (division), and `sub()` (subtraction).

Since you're using Solidity 0.8, SafeMath is not needed (but you would need it in older versions), and you can replace the functions with standard arithmetic operations.

Example 1:

```
_amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
    10**2
);
```

can be replaced with

```
(_amount * _taxFee) / (10**2);
```

Example 2:

```
tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
```

can be replaced with

```
tAmount - tFee - tLiquidity;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have not included the _getRate() function in my question but I have it along with SafeMath.

The only error I have is:

CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables. --> contracts/X.sol:828:80: | 828 | (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate()); | ^^^^^^^

Comment: I have to edit:

function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tMarketing) = _getTValues(tAmount);
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate());
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing);
}

Using https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep

I just don't know how

Comment: @cquenneville I don't know how to solve the "Stack too deep" error right now. But please describe your issue more clearly in the question next time. For example by pasting the exact error message and the code that anyone can copy-paste to their IDE and get the same error message. It makes it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you for the comment I'll do better next time

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try an reduce the uint size to something more appropriate to reduce the size of the stack, such as using uint8,16,32,64,128.

so, the range is:

```
uints8 = 0 to 255,
uint16 = 0 to 65535,
uint32 =  0 to 4,294,967,295,
uint64 = 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615,
uint128 = 0 to 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,455,
uint256 = 0 to 2**256 – 1
```

organizing the variables in order of storage size to try an pack as many variables into a storage slot that will fit
the slots are like 32 bytes long
so if you organize them something like,

```
string,
address,
uint256,
uint128,
uint64,
uint32,
uint32
```

you'll save gas
uint256 is 32 bytes so it will take up the entire slot, while the  128,64,32,32 will be concatenated into 1 slot